# Access method of jquery/coffeescript plugin from outside the plugin

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, coffeescript, public

I know this question has been asked several times, but all the answers confuse me, because I am unsure of how to get the coffeescript code to compile into that specified jquery code.

This is what I have so far:

```
pluginName = 'tagbox'

states = 
  none: 0
  typing: 1
  altering: 2        

defaults =
  editing: true
  tags: []

class Plugin
  constructor: (@element, options) ->
    @options = $.extend {}, defaults, options
    @_defaults = defaults
    @_states = states
    @state = states.none
    @_name = 'tagbox'
    @currentTag = $("<div class='ui-individualtag'></div>")

  # this is the public method I want
  setCurrentTag: (tagText) ->
    @currentTag.text(tagText)

$.fn[pluginName] = (options) ->
  @each ->
    if !$.data(this, "plugin_#{pluginName}")
      $.data(@, "plugin_#{pluginName}", new Plugin(@, options))
)(jQuery, window, document)
```

and then in another script, I want to be able to access the setCurrentTag method like this:

```
tagbox = $('#tagbox').tagbox()
tagbox.setCurrentTag("hello world")
```

Let me know if it will help to show what this compiles into in jquery.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi: There's also the jQuery-UI-style `$(x).tagbox('setCurrentTag', 'hello world')`. That's the closest thing to a standard approach that I've seen and avoids polluting the namespace while preserving chaining.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, but he asked for the other. It's a mess either way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `tagbox`:

```
tagbox = $('#tagbox').tagbox()
```

will be a jQuery object and that won't have a `setCurrentTag` method. You don't want to try to change this as that will break the usual jQuery chaining behavior. One way to solve this is to give the `tagbox` plugin enough intelligence to parse its arguments so that you can pass a method name in:

```
$('#tagbox').tagbox('setCurrentTag', 'hello world')
```

This is the approach that [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/) takes so it should be familiar to a lot of jQuery people.

All you'd need to do is modify your `$.fn.tagbox` to look more like this:

```
$.fn[pluginName] = (options = {}) ->
  if $.isPlainObject options
    @each ->
      if !$.data(@, "plugin_#{pluginName}")
        $.data(@, "plugin_#{pluginName}", new Plugin(@, options))
  else
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    @each ->
      p = $.data(@, "plugin_#{pluginName}")
      p[args[0]](args[1])
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/q2U7d/

Some things to note:

1. I've added a default (`(options = {}) ->`) so that `options` will always be there.
2. We can check if we have an options object using [`$.isPlainObject`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/), if there no options then we can assume that we're doing a method call instead. This is why we want the default in **1**.
3. We use `Array.prototype.slice.call` as a hack to convert the Array-like [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to a real array to make it easier to work with. We don't have to do this but it can save some confusion if we want to use Array methods (such as `pop`) and we need a reference to the outer `arguments` inside the `@each` callback anyway: `arguments` is context sensitive just like `this` is in (Coffee|Java)Script.